# Trigger one Azure pipeline from another Azure pipeline doesn't work

Tags: azure-pipelines

So I have been following the official documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops

but I am unable to achieve this. I have pipeline named "secondPipeline", I want it to run after the pipeline "firstPipeline" runs, "firstPipeline" would run after the commit.

Here is the yaml code, am I doing something wrong, this is supposed to be just a basic example?

firstPipeline.yml

```
name: firstPipeline
steps:
- bash: echo "first pipeline"
```

secondPipeline.yml:

```
name: secondPipeline
trigger: none
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: firstPipeline
    source: firstPipeline
    trigger: true


steps:
  - script: echo "second pipeline".
```

Both pipelines are defined in the same Azure DevOps project and in the same Azure DevOps repo. When creating the pipelines in AzureDevops I have also renamed the pipelines to "firstPipeline" and "secondPipeline". This is all on main branch.